# Django redirect after login is going in infinite loop

Tags: django, mongodb

This question has been answered earlier but those solutions are not working for me.
My setup have Django 1.9 and MongoDB as backend. I have custom user model.

I have a webpage where I am uploading files. that flow is working fine. Now I have to make that page login protected.
When I am trying to access `https://localhost/upload` it is redirecting me to `https://localhost/login_page?next=/upload`
I am giving correct credentials and I can see in django logs that it is redrecting me to `/upload` but again pointing me back to login page.

models.py

```
    class Uploadedfiles(models.Model):
        docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads')
```

views.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

    import os

    @login_required()
    def uploadfiles(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                newdoc = Uploadedfiles(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
                newdoc.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload'))
        else:
            form = UploadForm()  # A empty, unbound form

        ufiles = Uploadedfiles.objects.all()

        return render(
            request,
            'upload.html',
            {'ufiles': ufiles, 'form': form}
```

login_page.html

```
            <div>
    {% if next %}
    <form action="/login/?next={{ request.path }}" method="post" >
    {%else%}
    <form action="/login_page/" method="post" >
    {% endif %}
    {% csrf_token %}
        <p><b>Login</b></p>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="new_password">
                    <span id="message"></span>
                    <button type="submit" name="Login"><b>Login</b></button>
            </form>
            </div>
```

login view

```
    def LoginPage(request,*args, **kwargs):

        msg = "Please provide details"
        next = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', ''))

        if 'email' in request.POST and 'password' in request.POST:
            password=request.POST['password']
            email=request.POST['email']

            payload = { "password" : password, "email":email}
            response = requests.post('https://localhost/login',data=payload)
            code=response.status_code

            if '200'==code or 200==code:
                msg="Your are login successfully"
                print(msg)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/upload")

            else:
                msg=response[msg]
                response = render(request,'login_page.html',{'msg':msg})
        else:
            response = render(request,'login_page.html',{})
        return response
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^login$', Login.as_view(), name=r"login"), #This is REST API 
        url(r'^login_page/$', LoginPage, name=r"loginpage")
        ]
```

Please someone help me..

**EDIT 1** : adding custom user model

```
from mongoengine import fields, Document

class User(Document):
    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    username = fields.StringField(required=True)
    email = fields.EmailField()
    name = fields.StringField()
    password = fields.StringField(required=True)
```

Comment: You are redirecting to the `upload` view inside the `upload` view with `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload'))` probably causing the infinite redirect

Comment: @ritlew for that I have to go inside that code block. it is not going there.

Comment: Your implementation does not make sense. Why are you calling an API for logging in? What the relation between that API and your View?

Comment: @ruddra till now we have used API for login but for uploading files, we need webpage and we have to make that page login protected. So internally we are calling that API. Instad of APi we can call the respective serializer as well.

Answer (score 0):

[A simple solution would be to use LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/upload'
```

Comment: I want to use `next` for redirection

Comment: @pratibha try this return redirect('upload')

Comment: No it is still going in loop